# C# textbox disable shortcuts

Tags: c#, textbox, shortcut

i use a textbox inside my windows form application and i need to disable the shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. I tried many different solutions i found via google but it won't work.

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> already as a custom shortcut in my app and i do not want to have a tabstop inserted by this command inside my textbox. For whatever reason <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> acts like pressing delete?

If i set "Shortcuts enabled" to false in the properties of the control <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> are still working. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is disabled then. I would expect that all shortcuts are turned off if i set "Shortcuts enabled" to false.

I tried the following code i found somewhere but it also does not prevent <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

```
    private void textBoxComment_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.Modifiers == Keys.Control )
        {
            switch(e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.C:
                case Keys.X:
                case Keys.V:
                case Keys.Z:
                case Keys.I:
                case Keys.H:
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding `ProcessCmdKey` function:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
   if ((keyData & Keys.Control) > 0 && (keyData & Keys.KeyCode) == Keys.V)
   {
       return true;
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: I already have an override for CTRL+I which triggers a function to grab to current position from axAXVLCplugin. But when i press CTRL+I i get a tab in my textbox and the current position. So both is executed.

Answer (score 1):

This could help. I have ToolStripMenu with few items, which have ShorcutKeys. I wanted to stop their functionality while any TextBox has focus. This worked for me

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (ActiveControl is TextBox)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menu.DropDownItems)
            {
                if (item.ShortcutKeys == Keys.None) continue;

                if (item.ShortcutKeys == keyData)
                {
                    item.ShortcutKeys = Keys.None;

                    var ret = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

                    item.ShortcutKeys = keyData;

                    return ret;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcutsenabled property so you can be more selective in excluding shortcuts from mouse and from keyboard.

```
TextBox.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

Reference [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx)
Use the ShortcutsEnabled property to enable or disable the following shortcut key combinations and the control’s shortcut menu:
CTRL+Z
CTRL+E
CTRL+C
CTRL+Y
CTRL+X
CTRL+BACKSPACE
CTRL+V
CTRL+DELETE
CTRL+A
SHIFT+DELETE
CTRL+L
SHIFT+INSERT
CTRL+R

Comment: CTRL+H and CTRL+I are still working

private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs{
            textBoxComment.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
        }

Comment: MSDN does not explain how to 'use the ShortcutsEnabled property to enable or disable' CERTAIN key combinations, it only refers to using the boolean property to GLOBALLY turn all shortcuts on or off.  The only way I can see how to eliminate unwanted shortcut combinations is to specifically eat them in a Keydown handler (unless I am missing something).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` also:

```
private void textBoxComment_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Modifiers == Keys.Control )
    {
        switch(e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.C:
            case Keys.X:
            case Keys.V:
            case Keys.Z:
            case Keys.I:
            case Keys.H:
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jones I tested it, you said `Ctrl + H` seems to work like a `Backspace` and it indeed acts like that when I tested, (a little supprised), however when using the code I posted, **it's really disabled**. I think you may want to post more code.

Comment: I just tried with a blank form. So i added a textbox and below the function  public Form1() { InitializeComponent() } i have pasted your Code. Then CTRL+I is disabled but CTRL+H is still working. I cannot add more code because i am new to StackOverflow and i have only the right to comment in the moment.
But that does not explain why CTRL+I is still possible inside my other App. Perhaps because i use an Override for CTRL+I to trigger another function and because of that CTRL+I is still available inside the Textbox?

Comment: @Jones do you know how to register an event handler in `C#`? I doubt you haven't registered the handler for the `KeyDown` event. As I said, it works for me, you can try a new project and see it in action. The last question, **how do you know Ctrl + H is still enable?** Is the `character` still removed backward (like as you use `Backspace` when pressing `Ctrl + H`?