# How to disable a textbox keyboard shorcuts in c#?

Tags: c#, textbox, shortcut

I've just noticed that Textbox have a default shortcut so that whenever you press Ctrl + H, it starts with deleting letters as if you pressed BackSpace.

This can get quite annoying since I want to open a Form whenever Ctrl + H is pressed. Is there any way to stop the backspacing while still being able to use it to open the Windows Form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# textbox disable shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942708/c-sharp-textbox-disable-shortcuts)

Comment: @Kevin No bro :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTRL-H` is the ASCII BS (Backspace) character.

You can disable (or redefine) it, since CTRL+H and BackSpace are not exactly the same thing. There are a few examples listed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434867/how-to-use-multiple-modifier-keys-in-c-sharp) with other keys.

You need to add the `KeyEventHandler` in your `Form1.Designer.cs` like this:

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
```

And in your `Form1.cs` add this function:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.H && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
        //uncomment if ReadOnly is not working
        //e.SuppressKeyPress  = true;
        
        textbox1.ReadOnly = true;
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        textbox1.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the anwser, I found an existing KeyEventHandler in Form1.Designer.cs, I put textBox1_KeyDown as you wrote, but the same problem remained, after pressing Ctrl+H it opens the Form2 and also deletes a character from the Textbox1

Comment: I think I found a solution, I added to your answer textbox1.ReadOnly = true before opening Form2 and added textbox1.ReadOnly = false after opening it, and it doesn't delete a character after pressing Ctrl+H

Comment: @Alex probably it was the second form which was overwriting the **SuppressKeyPress** property. I'm glad that it worked.